# j_security_check Glassfish Error

Tags: jakarta-ee, authentication, glassfish, java-ee-7

I'm trying to build an application that utilizes FORM authentication, but when I run the example I get a screen that says:

```
An Error Occurred:

Index: 0, Size: 0
```

[Stack Trace](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1ubltQ2wZhk8L0y9uh711b-wMLDSCKQH1NykIFah-HRI/edit?usp=sharing)

I am running GlassFish Server Open Source Edition 4.0 (build 89)

The form's code:

```
<h:form class="form-signin" p:action="j_security_check">
    <h:inputText class="form-control top" p:name="j_username" p:placeholder="Username" p:autofocus="true" />
    <h:inputSecret class="form-control bottom" p:name="j_password" p:placeholder="Password" />
    <h:commandButton class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block" value="Login" />
</h:form>
```

web.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="3.1" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd">
    <display-name>myKitchen</display-name>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>javax.faces.PROJECT_STAGE</param-name>
        <param-value>Development</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
        <security-role-ref>
            <description/>
            <role-name>user</role-name>
            <role-link>User</role-link>
        </security-role-ref>
        <security-role-ref>
            <description/>
            <role-name>User</role-name>
            <role-link>User</role-link>
        </security-role-ref>
        <security-role-ref>
            <description/>
            <role-name>admin</role-name>
            <role-link>Admin</role-link>
        </security-role-ref>
        <security-role-ref>
            <description/>
            <role-name>Admin</role-name>
            <role-link>Admin</role-link>
        </security-role-ref>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/app/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <session-config>
        <session-timeout>
            30
        </session-timeout>
    </session-config>
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>app/index.xhtml</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
    <security-constraint>
        <display-name>User Pages</display-name>
        <web-resource-collection>
            <web-resource-name>User Pages Area</web-resource-name>
            <description>Pages that only authenticated users should be able to use</description>
            <url-pattern>/protected/*</url-pattern>
        </web-resource-collection>
        <auth-constraint>
            <description/>
            <role-name>Admin</role-name>
            <role-name>User</role-name>
        </auth-constraint>
        <user-data-constraint>
            <description/>
            <transport-guarantee>NONE</transport-guarantee>
        </user-data-constraint>
    </security-constraint>
    <security-role>
        <description>Regular user</description>
        <role-name>User</role-name>
    </security-role>
    <security-role>
        <description>Admin user</description>
        <role-name>Admin</role-name>
    </security-role>
    <login-config>
        <auth-method>FORM</auth-method>
        <realm-name>JDBCRealm</realm-name>
        <form-login-config>
            <form-login-page>/app/index.xhtml</form-login-page>
            <form-error-page>/app/errors/auth.xhtml</form-error-page>
        </form-login-config>
    </login-config>
</web-app>
```

glassfish-web.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE glassfish-web-app PUBLIC "-//GlassFish.org//DTD GlassFish Application Server 3.1 Servlet 3.0//EN" "http://glassfish.org/dtds/glassfish-web-app_3_0-1.dtd">
<glassfish-web-app error-url="">
  <security-role-mapping>
    <role-name>user</role-name>
    <group-name>user</group-name>
    <group-name>User</group-name>
  </security-role-mapping>
  <security-role-mapping>
    <role-name>admin</role-name>
    <group-name>admin</group-name>
    <group-name>Admin</group-name>
  </security-role-mapping>
  <security-role-mapping>
    <role-name>Admin</role-name>
    <group-name>admin</group-name>
    <group-name>Admin</group-name>
  </security-role-mapping>
  <security-role-mapping>
    <role-name>User</role-name>
    <group-name>user</group-name>
    <group-name>User</group-name>
  </security-role-mapping>
  <class-loader delegate="true"/>
  <jsp-config>
    <property name="keepgenerated" value="true">
      <description>Keep a copy of the generated servlet class' java code.</description>
    </property>
  </jsp-config>
</glassfish-web-app>
```

And the tutorial I followed: [link](http://blog.eisele.net/2013/01/jdbc-realm-glassfish312-primefaces342.html)

Comment: Please show the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Defining a database connection password fixed the problem